# How to automatically split text input into separate tweets

Tags: android, twitter

I'm writing an android app in which I'm posting to twitter, but if the post has characters over 140, it shows an exception.

My requirement is to take the characters from 140 onwards and put them in the next tweet. Can anyone can suggest a solution?

Comment: Show us your current code, so we could suggest something that is related to your case.

Answer (score 2):

Before calling post you should bucket your input String to a max 140 characters each. Then afterwards, you simply call post to twitter for each bucket. Additionally, you might want the bucketing to take account of logical words separation so it doesn't get cut off mid way and present indication to the user of a longer tweet.

Comment: can you suggest me some sample code to look into so as to make myself comfortable doing the same.

Comment: what if i wanna restrict the user from typing after 140 characters.I mean user shouldn't be able to type after 140 characters.How do i do this??

Comment: Show us your current code, but likely you just add a listener that would track the number of characters that have been typed

Answer (score 1):

charset 140 should be a simple solution

Comment: what if i wanna restrict the user from typing after 140 characters.I mean user shouldn't be able to type after 140 characters.How do i do this??